CSS selector for the first element that has a certain child element
My first thought was that I could potentially combine the has() selector with the :first-of-type selector like this: .parent-item-selector:has(.child-item-selector):first-of-type and that it would result in the first instance of .parent-item-selector in which there is a child element of .child-item-selector and that then I could style only that first element.
I'm able to use .parent-item-selector:has(.child-item-selector) to successfully style all of the parent elements that have that certain child, but of course it does not target the first one.
Is this kind of combination possible?
To give a more specific example, this works:
.parent-item-selector:has(.child-item-selector) {
    background-color:#0ebac5;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

But what I need does not work, and I'm trying to figure out if there is another way that has() can help:
.parent-item-selector:has(.child-item-selector):first-of-type) {
    background-color:#0ebac5;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


Give us a code example. Much easier to debug and see what you're doing than trying to read a paragraph about it.

Okay, sure. So this works:
.parent-item-selector:has(.child-item-selector)) {
    background-color:#0ebac5;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

And this does not:
.parent-item-selector:has(.child-item-selector):first-of-type) {
    background-color:#0ebac5;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


You should attach a code sample

Edit your question with stack snippet. Not a comment with your code. See this working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gvwaf5t9/ - now what do you have? You have extra closing parenthesis in your examples.

Voting to reopen because it's not exactly the same as an arbitrary selector within the nth-child

https://jsfiddle.net/xrwadzu7/12/ as i can't post it as an answer because it is closed i post it as a comment

@TheWuif I already posted a working fiddle in my comment. We would still need to see OPs original code, because it works in a simple example.

@TheWuif this one works for me. I'm not entirely sure why the first fiddle doesn't work, but thanks for this one.

@disinfor your code is not working exacly like it should. see: https://jsfiddle.net/9btzpmda/ the style is not applied correctly if the element is not the first.,

@TheWuif and that's why we need OPs actual code. Nice work!
